# How to set properties of subcontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I need a lot of buttons that contain an Image and a Text. That is why I do not want to use

```
<Button>
  <Image></Image>
  <TextBlock></TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Therefore I created a new ImageTextButton

```
public class ImageTextButton: Button
{ 
  public TextBlock Label
  {
    get { return (Label)GetValue( LabelProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( LabelProperty, value ); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                       name: nameof( Label ),
                                                                       propertyType: typeof( TextBlock ),
                                                                       ownerType: typeof( ImageTextButton ) );

  public PSImage Image
  {
    get { return (Image)GetValue( ImageProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( ImageProperty, value ); }
    }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                       name: nameof( Image ),
                                                                       propertyType: typeof( Image ),
                                                                       ownerType: typeof( ImageTextButton) );

  public ImageTextButton()
  {
    StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
    panel.Children.Add( Image );
    panel.Children.Add( Label );
    panel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    Content = panel;
  }
```

Setting the text in the c# code works perfectly but is it also possible to enter it in XAML?

Can you please help me or give me a hint?

Comment: You should add a `string` dependency to your class instead of a `Label` prooperty. The `Label` element should be defined in the template of the custom control and bind to the `string` dependency property.

Comment: @mm8 thanks for your reply, but setting the text was only an example. I want to be generic and able to set all properties of the Textbox and the image.

Comment: Then you need to define these properties. You can't do something like `<local:ImageTextButton LabelProperty.Content="some string.." />` in XAML. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `string` dependency to your class instead of a `Label` property. You could then simply set the property of the control in XAML like this:

```
<local:ImageTextButton YourTextProperty="some string.." />
```

The `Label` element should be defined in the template of the custom control and bind to the `string` dependency property.

And the `ImageTextButton` class should probably be a `UserContol` instead of a custom control as it just a composite of built-in controls:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Button>
        <Image></Image>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourTextProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"></TextBlock>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Of course you may add several other dependency properties to the `UserControl` and bind these to the corresponding properties of the elements in the XAML the same way.

I am afraid you can't do something like `<local:ImageTextButton LabelProperty.Content="some string.." />` in XAML.

You could of course set a `Label` dependency property to a `Label` element like this if that's what you want:

```
<local:ImageTextButton>
    <local:ImageTextButton.Label>
        <Label Content="..." /> 
     </local:ImageTextButton.Label>
</local:ImageTextButton>
```

Comment: yes I tried your suggestion but you always replace the label or image on the button instead of extending it. Since there seems to be no easy solution I added bindable properties to the button that will give its content to the label/image.

Comment: So you did go with my first suggestion then?